# changing drupal 6 form and submit for exsiting content type

Tags: drupal, forms, submit, cck

hey i got a contnet type that i made and i want to twweak it some , when i do form alter its all good but once i do submit its ignore my changes that i added a field for  example, how can i do that changes and tell him to insert also that field? do i need to put all the fields again in hook_submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  //...
  $form['#submit'][] = 'YOURMODULE_submitfunction';
  //...
}

function YOURMODULE_submitfunction($form, &$form_state) {
  // Save your own changes here to DB or something other
}
```

Comment: i mean that how can i do that i will implment my changes without now moving on to the whole cck fields and do validate myself? ie i changed only 1 field but in cck i did in the "create content " 10 cck fields so now i need to programmaticly insert them into the submit funcion?

Comment: hehe, $form['#submit'] - it's array of submits, so you don't override cck submitting functions. You should only save own changes as i wrote in comment. CCK will save own. Clear?